# Sobra de espaço no DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tenho um DataGridView que tem como source uma DataTable.
Porém ficou uma borda cinza sobrando abaixo da última linha.
Gostaria que o espaço que coloquei no formulário para o DataGrid fosse completamente preenchido.
Tentei algumas propriedades das rows mas sem sucesso.
Agradeço sugestões.[image: é essa borda cinza no final do DataGridView]

Comment: Desculpe, essa borda cinza é campo de preenchimento? Tem um  estrela ao lado (*)? Já sei! tem poucos registros e é tamanho ocupado da datagrid!

Comment: Não tem estrela,  é como se fosse a sobra do que o dataTable não preencheu.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao SOpt! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: é essa borda cinza no final do DataGrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não... Talvez seja isso:

```
int s1 = 0;
int s2 = 0;

s1 = (Int32)dataGridView1.RowCount;

for (int i = 0; i < s1; i++)
{
    s2 += dataGridView1.Rows[i].Height;
}

dataGridView1.Height = s1 * s2;
```

Veja também:

[DataGridViewRowCollection.GetRowsHeight(DataGridViewElementStates) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.getrowsheight?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Não ficou legal... precisa de algum ajuste...

Comment: Obrigado! fiz uns ajustes para o meu projeto mas deu certo!